# Load custom serviceModel in C#

Tags: c#, app-config

In my C# program I load a custom app.config, using this code:

```
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = location };
Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

In my `app.config`, there is also a section `<system.serviceModel>` with a service reference. This server reference is used like this:

```
var client = new MyClient();
```

However, this client is using the configuration of the original `app.config`, and not of the loaded configuration from the "Config".
How can I use a the serviceModel part from an external `app.config`?